# How to change default face for embolden text in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I do love thin fonts, so I have following customisation in my `.emacs`:

```
(set-frame-font "NK57 Monospace-14:weight=light" t)
```

This works as expected, however this does not tells Emacs that it should render embolden text with lighter weight too, e.g. to use `medium` instead of `regular` weight, so there is dramatically difference in weights, see picture below.

[image]

How can I tweak this?

Comment: If you place your cursor on any of the faces you want to change, you can type `C-u C-x =` and obtain the information about what is present at point.  You can customize faces to have the weight you desire.  Alternatively you can pace your cursor at the point and type `M-x customize-face RET`

Comment: Thanks, @lawlist, very helpful! However, I've discovered that (in my current case) customising default `bold` face do not gives desired effect, instead I have to override `font-lock` customisations _(e.g. `font-lock-function-name-face`, `font-lock-keyword-face`, etc.)_. However, this settings could come from colour theme (if I not mistaken). So what I really need is to override _(programmatically?)_ all font-lock embolden faces.

Comment: It sounds like you wish to modify the core behavior of Emacs, which is possible, but certainly not an easy task.  The easiest solution would be to spend time customizing the faces for whatever modes and/or themes that you normally use -- this is how Emacs has been designed to be used.  That being said, you could look into modifying the core functions dealing with faces within `custom.el` and `faces.el`.  Some of the core functions are likely at the C-source level, and are thus not easily changed.  You could also look into restricting certain font sets from being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is possible to customise default bold face using `customize-face` command as was mentioned by **lawlist** *(i.e. Easy [Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html))*.

However, this is not enough in most cases, because of some packages or themes could introduce another customisations, which overrides default one (e.g. `font-lock-function-name-face`, `font-lock-keyword-face`) and could be found in face customisation menu too.